# Append 'Called by reference variables' to a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, for-loop, foreach

I am writing test cases in Selenium web driver and I want to output the results to a log file. The test cases should be numbered per line in a text file. The numbering has been achieved, but appending the test cases is something I have not been able to achieve. The problem is the for loop where I want to append the combination of variables passed by reference. These variables will be the test cases. If more explanation is needed, please let me know.

The problem is that concatenating the defined variables only appends one value for all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static int counter;
        public static String[] test = {"1", "2" };
        public static String[] test1 = { "a", "b" };

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            new Class1().testing2();
        }

        public String testing(String ab, String cd)
        {
            //Count the number of times the method is called
            ++counter;
            //Write it to a text file
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\WriteLines.txt", counter.ToString());
            //Read from that text file
            String Readfiles = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\WriteLines.txt");
            //Convert to integer
            Int32 myInt = Int32.Parse(Readfiles);
            //Store in array variable
            String[] start = new String[myInt];
            //iterate through
            for (int i = 0; i < myInt; ++i)
            {
                **start[i] = (i + 1).ToString() +ab +cd;**
            }
            //Write into another text file on new lines
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\Writing.txt", start);

            String gb = ab; String th = cd; String you = ab + cd;
            return you;   
        }

        public void testing2()
        { 
            foreach(var item in Class1.test)
            {
                foreach (var item1 in Class1.test1)
                {
                    String test = testing(item, item1);
                    Console.WriteLine(test);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran it this is the output in the text file:

```
1 2b
2 2b
3 2b
4 2b
```

what I want to output in the text file is:

```
1 1a
2 1b
3 2a
4 2b
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you show what the method outputs and what you really wanted it to output?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited it added the output I am expecting.

Comment: What does this line mean `**start[i] = (i + 1).ToString() +ab +cd;**` ? Do you mean `start[i] = (i + 1).ToString() +ab +cd;` ?

Comment: This where exactly the problem is. What it means is that append to each numbered line the variables passed by reference. What I want is that for each iteration add to each line the concatenation of the variables called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a global variable

```
public static String[] lines = { };
```

Change `testing()` to this:

```
    public String testing(String ab, String cd)
    {
        //Count the number of times the method is called
        ++counter;
        //Write it to a text file
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\WriteLines.txt", counter.ToString());
        //Read from that text file
        String Readfiles = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\WriteLines.txt");
        //Convert to integer
        Int32 myInt = Int32.Parse(Readfiles);
        //Store in array variable
        String start = myInt.ToString() + ab + cd;
        //Store the new data in the array
        Array.Resize(ref lines, lines.Length + 1);
        lines[lines.GetUpperBound(0)] = start;
        //Write into another text file on new lines
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\Writing.txt", lines);
        //String gb = ab; String th = cd;
        String you = ab + cd;

        return you;   
    }
```

Since `WriteAllText` means to overwrite the file.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myInt; ++i)
{
    start[i] = (i + 1).ToString() +ab +cd;
}
```

The code above `(ab + cd)` equals `2b`, which means you are only changing the line number, and `2b` stays the same.

Comment: The better way is to append the output file. But it'll be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Am I to create a variable "lines"? This throws an error that it does not exist in the current context. Appreciate. If yes, What data type?

Comment: Add a global variable `lines`. See the first line of my answer.

Comment: Below `String[] test1 = { "a", "b" };`

Comment: Thanks. Words aren't enough to appreciate. The problem solved!